# sbt build failed for spark scala with xgboost

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, xgboost

./build/sbt clean package
gives the below error:

```
Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
   [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
   [warn]   ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
   [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
   [warn]   :: ml.dmlc.xgboost#xgboost4j_2.10;0.7: not found
   [warn]   :: ml.dmlc.xgboost#xgboost4j-spark_2.10;0.7: not found
   [warn]   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

build.sbt looks like below:

```
name := "xgboostproj"
version := "1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.6.1"
resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal
libraryDependencies += "ml.dmlc.xgboost" %% "xgboost4j" % "0.7"
libraryDependencies += "ml.dmlc.xgboost" %% "xgboost4j-spark" % "0.7"
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: `Warnings` doesn't mean the failed build, if you have errors, provide them.

Answer (score 2):

xgboost jars must be built locally and published to your local maven repository for your set up to work. The instructions for this is published [here](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jvm/)

Also additionally the dependencies should be like below (the groupId is ml.dmlc)

```
libraryDependencies += "ml.dmlc" %% "xgboost4j" % "0.7"
libraryDependencies += "ml.dmlc" %% "xgboost4j-spark" % "0.7"
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Yes, I have built xgboost and have the xgboost jars in the xgboostproj/lib directory. I even added unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / "lib" to the built.sbt. I still face this error.

Comment: @MahalakshmiLakshminarayanan if you added the built directory in the lib directory you dont need the libraryDependencies settings for both xgboost4j and xgboost4j-spark. please remove those 2 lines from the build file and try compiling the project

Comment: I get these errors if I removed libraryDependencies: [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/maha/xgboostproj/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /home/maha/xgboostproj/src/main/scala/BoostSpark.scala:6: object dmlc is not a member of package org.apache.spark.ml
[error] import ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.spark.XGBoost
[error]           ^
[error] /home/maha/xgboostproj/src/main/scala/BoostSpark.scala:32: not found: value XGBoost
[error]     val model = XGBoost.train(trainRDD, paramMap, numRound, nWorkers = 5, useExternalMemory = true)

Answer (score 0):

I think the dependencies should be changed to:

```
libraryDependencies += "ml.dmlc" % "xgboost4j" % "0.7"
libraryDependencies += "ml.dmlc" % "xgboost4j-spark" % "0.7"
```

Also make sure your sbt is looking at the local maven repo. These were the two things that I needed to fix to make it work. Also make sure the jar files exist in the m2 repo. This is assuming you used mvn install to build the jvm packages.